# dotnetnuke how to copy pages programatically

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have thousands of pages which i need to export from qa to production. I have seen the export page function but is there a way to do this in batch? I have found code to create pages but not to extract them. All permissions and settings must also be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Portal Templates (export) feature found under the Host/Sites page.

That will generate a template for the site, then you could transfer that to production (that would be a couple of files) and "apply" that template to your existing site.

The other option would be to backup/restore the database, that is how most people handle changes between staging/production. Though that assumes any changes already made in Production exist in Staging.

Comment: QA and production are not the same. I cannot replace production site with qa - this is not an option. I need to extract some pages from qa (not all) and add them to production.

Comment: However for solution 1 - can i export to xml then modify the xml then import? Would you recommend doing this?

Comment: Yes that would likely be your best option